# What type of iPhone application file should I use?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, tabbar

What type of iPhone application file should I use?

Before, I was trying to make an application that gets information from an RSS, then populates a tableview.

The application would be using a Tab Bar, and have many different views.

Before I tried using a "Tab Bar Application" but I did some stuff wrong (I am not sure what) and I had to start over.

So which app-type should I use?

Thanks!
 -Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a tab bar based application, make a Tab Bar Application.

It seems that you're still pretty new to things, so it may actually be more beneficial to make a blank application, and learn how to create the tab bar application from scratch.  There's very little magic going on in there and then when "it breaks" you'll know how to fix it.

Comment: I'll take your advice and use a blank app!
(And your right, I am new to this)
Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie and while playing around with TabBar template, I wanted to add a navigation controller to one of the tab views. I messed around completely and started it again atleast twice.

From my mistakes, I learnt that the best way to customize a tab bar app is to start by opening the MainWindow.xib file in IB. Open that file and Press Cmd+0. It will open a window showing the objects in the nib file. You should normally see a tab bar controller, an app delegate and probably a file's owner. There expand the "TabBarController". Your different views will be listed there and each will be inheriting from UIViewController by default. You can change them by dragging a "NavigationController" from the library on to the view. Its as simple as that. Avoid going through that Window Based App template. Try using the template files. If you get stuck do it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whichever one you want. The "application types" are only templates to get you started. You can modify them in any way and the template you choose doesn't restrict you at all.

Comment: So which one would you recommend?